# Synchronize between ViewControllers for background parse fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have multiple View Controllers in my iOS app , and I use parse to fetch some data.
The main VC has something like this:

```
-(void)readAndFetchGroups
{

 //Fire up a thread to fetch online groups in background
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(fetchOnlineGroupsInBackground) withObject:nil];

}
-(void)fetchOnlineGroupsInBackground
{
 [Group fetchOnlineGroups:self];
}
```

Group is my model class and the method fetch online groups will fetch the data from the parse cloud and it goes something like this

```
 NSMutableArray* onlineGroups=[NSMutableArray array];

 PFUser* currUser=[PFUser currentUser];
 //Is the user cached?
 if (currUser) {
 PFRelation *relation = [currUser relationForKey:@"groups"];
 //Make the query and fetch the data ,save result in objects

    for (PFObject* object in objects) {
        //Did the group admin remove me? or am I still a member?
        if ([Group iamAMemberInOnlineGroup:object]) {
            Group* group=[Group groupFromPFObject:object];
            if (group) {
                [onlineGroups addObject:group];

            }
        }
        //I was removed from group by admin , remove this group from my relation
        else
        {
            [relation removeObject:object];

        }

 [currUser save];
  }
```

The problem is that I have a settings VC which gives the option to log out
so if the fetch is running in the background and the user logs out I get an exception from the background running thread

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'User 
    cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or  signUp'
```

From what I looked up , killing a running thread is evil and could cause lots of problems.

Is my best option here to have a flag set when a fetch is active and if that flag is raised disable logging off?
If yes , how do I do it?
I mean how do I have a variable that is shared among all controllers

Thanks

Comment: One idea is to put up a "busy" UI while the group thing is running, a thing that lets the user know that they can't navigate until a quick transaction gets done.  The other idea would a semaphore in the Group class that is set before the parse call and unset in the completion block.  Your gcd code could be cleaned up a lot if you used only the `...WithBlock: ` versions of the parse calls and gave your fetchOnlineGroups method a block param of its own.  That would also make the semaphore code clearer and less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to implement this would be to send a `NSNotification` out when the user logs out. Register your class that is making the query as an observer of the logging out `NSNotification`. Inside that class maintain a list of all active queries. When the user logs out call `cancel` on your `PFQuery`.

[Canceling a query in Parse](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/cancel)

Comment: Yeah but the exception is not raised by the query , its raised by save method  in pfuser.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `Singleton` to set/remove your flag. This method can solve your problem, but for a better solution you should lock users interaction(with a hud maybe) before you fetch data from server. Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that I have offline and online groups and I don't wanna to prevent my users from interacting with their offline groups because there is a fetch running in the background